# Is there a common design pattern or object oriented approach used to encapsulate thread behaviour?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, design-patterns, pthreads

I have recently been using pthreads on Linux and want to start looking into using boost threads in the near future. I have never used MS visual studio so I don't know the approach there but I (have to) use Embarcadero C++ Builder (formerly Borland) one of the few good things I find with it is that is has a built in class `TThread`. This is a class that you can derive from to give nicely encapsulated data and start and terminate functions.  I prefer this approach than the pthread way of passing functions and `void*` being passed into the thread create function. I was wondering if there is some kind of design pattern or structure that is commonly used to provide a more object oriented that encapsulates the functionality of threads in this way? I can try and create it myself, but I cannot be the first person to desire this kind of approach and wondered if there was a "standard" way of achieving it.

Edit: Alternatively, if this is a very bad idea perhaps an illustration of why?

Comment: _Why_ do you want an OOP threading framework? Threads by their very nature are action-driven (they execute code), so a functional approach makes more sense to me.

Comment: I would like to be able to create an instance of a class, pass it data, start it when I like and terminate it when I like as an object with all internal functionality hidden from the code that uses it. It is not *that* controversial an idea is it??

Comment: But how is that better than calling a function with arguments? What is a class buying you other than potential shared-state trouble?

Comment: Note that the approach you mention in Embarcadero (which is the same as deriving from `Thread` in Java) is not a good approach and is in many cases prone to errors. Currently the trend is to have a `Thread` class that just manages the thread, and takes a *job* to run as an argument (Boost, C++11, Java Runnable approach)

Comment: @mathematician1975 - it is somewhat controversial.  I have spend 30+ years trying to stop Delphi developers from doing exactly that - continually starting and terminating threads.  TThread is just fine for implementing thread pools and lifetime-of-app threads that never require termination.  Attempting to encapsulate thread termination will cause you pain, eventually - try very hard indeed to not do it.  There is no inherent shared-state problem with TThread or any C++ implementation of a 'TThread-like' class - each instance would have its own instance vars and stack - no problemo.

Comment: Well with any luck I will soon be removed from ever needing to use embarcadero environment ever again. From the responses hear I will forget the idea completely.

Comment: ..and now, newer languages seem to teach developers to use join(), (AKA TThread.waitFor), for 'returning' results from threads, the very thing I have not touched since D3 and have tried to stop others using, <sigh>.  Use thread pools and/or app-lifetime threads and you will have few problems.

Comment: @mathematician1975 - there is nothing wrong with the Borland/Embarcadero TThread model except that is so often misused, ably assisted by the Borland TThread examples that are just dire.  A producer-consumer queue takes 22 lines of TObjectQueue descendant and making a thread pool is then just trivial - two lines of code.

Comment: Oh dear. TThread class was my first introduction to multithreading as were those examples that you mention. Seems I will have learned some bad habits then....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider that the most *standard* approach would be using the standard thread library (closely related to `boost::thread`, not 100% the same). I would avoid redesigning what has already been designed, reviewed and verified by a committee of experts.

Also note that for the kind of operations that you mention in the comment you might want to take a look at the *future* part of the standard library (again similar to the boost counterpart), and in particular to the `std::asynch` function.

Comment: This is part of C++11 I presume? I am not actually able to use that at present which I probably should have specified. Perhaps my question is outdated then with the advent of C++11

Comment: @mathematician1975: Just use `boost::thread`, `boost::future`... whenever you get to use C++11 the changes in code will be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way boost::thread is designed (I saw a similar design in the threading library from Rouge Wave). Basically a thread is started by passing a function to be executed and latter that thread object can be used to join that thread. pthread is very similar in design, but boost::thread is much easier to use.